# Generating DLL out of Simulink model

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, dll, simulink

I'd be interested in knowing if any of you has direct experience in porting Simulink models into working DLL (Dynamic Linking Library).

I am aware of this document:

[From Simulink to DLL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9709-from-simulink-to-dll-a-tutorial)

but it is a rather outdated documentation. Perhaps there exist faster ways to accomplish this task successfully.

**EDIT**

As far as I understood, I just proceed this way:

- Derive a custom TLC from the grt.tlc file using the "Custom Target" example in the RTW Embedded Coder documentation, which does NOT require RTWEC, only RTW.
- Derive a custom TMF from the grt_vc.tmf file.
- Finally derive a C file.

Does it make sense or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Embedded Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/embedded-coder/), you can use the `ert_shrlib.tlc` target, see for example [How can I create a DLL target for RTW so I can create a DLL from my Simulink model that can be called from other C/Fortran programs?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-2F3I19/index.html).

Failing that, you'll have to manually create the DLL from the generated C code using Visual Studio or other IDE.